# Slider operating force range

Tags: datasheet, potentiometer, mechanical

I'm reading the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/54/ptb-777940.pdf) of `PTB0153-2010BPB103`. It states:

```
Mechanical Characteristics
Operating Force ................10 to 100 gf
Stop Strength ................. 5 kgf min.
Sliding Life .................. 15,000 cycles
Soldering Condition ........... 300 °C max. within 3 seconds
Travel ........................ 45, 60, 100 mm
```

The `Travel` allows different values, but in the "How to order" section I can see how it's defined.

What about the `Operating Force`? It says "10 to 100 gf" but I don't understand which is the actual value.

I don't think it's a tolerance because it's an order of magnitude. I'm also thinking about some different operating conditions but I don't see any meaning in that.

What does this specification mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The Travel allows different values, but in the "How to order" section
> I can see how it's defined.*

[image]

- For a 45 mm travel the part number begins PTB 45....
- For a 60 mm travel the part number begins PTB 60....
- For a 100 mm travel the part number begins PTB 01....

> *What about the Operating Force? It says "10 to 100 gf" but I don't
> understand which is the actual value.*

That's the force needed to start moving the slider. It's somewhere between 10 g and 100 g (a stiction value plus sliding force value). [Data sheet](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/54/ptb-777940.pdf).

This value isn't an "order option" number. It's a variable value that applies to all the sliders in this product range.

Comment: I don't understand why you explained me how to retrieve the Stroke length when I said I know that :) So, the answer of my question is there is a tolerance of 10 times for this value? Ouch...

Comment: @Mark the *travel* is the *stroke length* - you asked how it is defined and I explained. Maybe you meant something else?

Comment: I never asked how it's defined! Please read again my question. I only stated that for the stroke length (travel) they defined the models inside the order code, but they didn't do this for the operating force (I thought there were different versions)

Comment: OK, I misread your can as can't. The operating force is not a fixed definable value. It remains the same for all models @Mark - the part number contains no reference to the force value.